# How to share any file using google drive api v2 for Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, google-api, windows-phone-8.1, google-drive-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I am using Google.Apis.Drive.v2 for dotnet.

I am trying to integrate google drive in my own `Windows Phone 8.1` app, but i am not able to get a share link for a file which can be used by anyone to download that file.
Any kind of help is appreciated.

Auth code:

```
if (service != null) return; 

credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync( 
         new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/client_secret.json"), 
         new[] { DriveService.Scope.Drive },
         "user",
         CancellationToken.None); 
var initializer = new BaseClientService.Initializer() {  
     HttpClientInitializer = credential, }; 

service = new DriveService(initializer); 
service.HttpClient.Timeout = new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0); 
}
```

request:

```
var list = DriveService.Files.List(); 
foreach (var item in list.Items) { 
  string sharingLink = item.WebContentLink; }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to stack please read:  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask you will need to show us the code you are working with and any errors it is returning before we can assist you.

Comment: I list all the files using the DriveService object, then for each file i am using item.WebContentLink to share the file publically.
But when i try to open that link on a browser, it says "We're sorry, but you do not have access to this page.That’s all we know."
                                                                                                                           
I am using this code :
var list =  DriveService.Files.List();

   foreach (var item in list.Items)
                {
                 string sharingLink = item.WebContentLink;    
                }

Comment: can you post how you have created DriveService?   did you rememver to do list.execute()?

Comment: if (service != null)
                    return;
                credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                    new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/client_secret.json"),
                    new[] { DriveService.Scope.Drive },
                    "user",
                    CancellationToken.None);
                var initializer = new BaseClientService.Initializer()
                {  HttpClientInitializer = credential,          };
             service = new DriveService(initializer);
             service.HttpClient.Timeout = new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0); }

Answer (score 0):

remember to do execute.

```
var result = service.Files.List().Execute();
foreach (var item in result.Items) 
    { 
    string sharingLink = item.WebContentLink; 
    }
```

**Update for comment:**

File permissions are a nightmare.  First update request that you send everything.  which means if you had the permission Id from the file you could do a permissions get and change what ever you want in that then update that back.   If you just want to change one thing you can use patch along with the permission id from the file.

```
Permission patchedPermission = new Permission();
patchedPermission.Type= anyone;
service.Permissions.Patch(patchedPermission, fileId, permissionId).Execute();
```

Comment: i tried this also , but it gives the same result. i think there's something to do with permissions of the file , so i tried this :  Permission newPermission = new Permission();
  newPermission.Type = "anyone";
  newPermission.Id = PermissionId;
var permission = await service.Permissions.Update(newPermission, GoogleDriveItemID, PermissionId).ExecuteAsync(); and later i reload the list but still the permissions dont change and hence the file is inaccessible.

Comment: updated answer.   Try that if it doesn't work I think I am going to have to do some testing myself, currently doing this from memory.   I really hate file permissions.

Comment: I am fetching the file permission of the file, then changing the type field to "anyone" then updating it, followed by reloading the list , but the result is still the same.  Here is the code:

 var per = await service.Permissions.Get(GoogleDriveItemID, PermissionId).ExecuteAsync();
 per.Type = "anyone";
 GoogleDriveModel.service.Permissions.Update(per, GoogleDriveItemID, PermissionId).Execute();
 var list = await service.Files.List().ExecuteAsync();

Comment: do a get after your update see if it changed it or not.   There is a bunch of issues on the support forums about permissions not getting updated.

Comment: yes you are right , i did the same thing and the permission is not getting changed even after an update

Comment: i tried patch but it isn't working. Is there any other way in which i am able to share a file with another person using a link.?

Comment: check what .AlternateLink  has I normally use that one I have never tried using WebContentLink  tbh.   AlternateLink   is like when you click on the website to get a link to share with someone without having to give them permissions to the file.    AlternateLink  should be usable buy anyone that has the link.  My tutorial on the topic http://www.daimto.com/google-drive-api-link-to-file/